# How do you say "lonely hearts" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm having fun going through dictionaries to find Esperanto terms for various terms related to current technology, I've been successful with browsing, blogging, YouTube, nearly anything with social networks (via setting my Facebook language to E-o), Q&A sites, etc. One term that eludes me is **lonely hearts** (I hope I got it right in English!), a website or magazine column where you can advertise for finding a relationship.

I would guess at some combination of *-il-* or *-ej-* with *am'* or with *koramik'* or with *renkont'* but I experimented around and it never really expresses the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that the answer to "How do you say 'lonely hearts' in Esperanto?" is "You don't."

As a native English speaker, I was unfamiliar with the term "lonely hearts" and a search for the term yielded a few different definitions.

If you're asking more generally about what to call dating websites, you might consider something with *edz-peranto* or *svati*.

I'm particular to *reta svatejo*. Maybe it will catch on.

Comment: I'll take your word on this. Thank you for the alternatives, I think they do a good job!